# Running bash script/program with limited resources

Tags: java, bash

I am using a tool for generating PDF files, which is unfortunately not 100% reliable. Sometimes this tool gets into infinite loop and consumes 100% memory and processor as well.

I am running this tool from my Java app with `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("command")`.

1. Is there a way to set maximum execution time/memory for this process directly in the Java command?
2. If not directly from Java, is there a way to wrap the command into some bash tool, that would limit the resources?

I prefer the command to fail than utilise all the resources and basically kill the server.

**EDIT**:

Based on the `ulimit` suggestions I am trying this:

```
Runtime.getRuntime()
       .exec(arrayOf("bash", "-c", "ulimit -m 2; ulimit -a; pdfprint"))
```

I can see the ulimit works:

```
core file size          (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) unlimited
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 2
open files                      (-n) 10240
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 1
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 709
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 2
```

The strange thing is that I expected the `pdfprint` to crash because it wouldn't have enough memory. However that does not happen and the program runs correctly.

Comment: Since we're talking bash, I assume `command` is already a script. Can't you just set ulimits (data size etc, stack size etc) in the script before calling whatever app actually does the PDF stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The better solution is to edit your bash script and add limits.

You can limit the memory usage by a Bash Script, doing the follow.

Limit the memory usage by kb (2GB in this example):

```
ulimit -m 2048000
```

Limit virtual memory usage:

```
ulimit -v 2048000
```

Set virtual memory limit to be hard limit, so that process will be killed when exceeding this limit:

```
ulimit -H -v
```

For CPU limiting you can use `cpulimit` tool

Comment: This helped. I was just confused, that OSX doesn't respect these limits, so it works on the server, but not in my dev environemnet.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if Runtime is mandatory for you , but it was used with java JDK < 5 , afterwards **ProcessBuilder** was introduced .
With ProcessBuilder you can combine **Process** and [waitFor(..)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#waitFor-long-java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit-) method.
From java 8 they introdced parameters to this method.

Looks like (taken from original guide):

```
boolean waitFor(long timeout, TimeUnit unit)
```

> Causes the current thread to wait, if necessary, until the subprocess
>   represented by this Process object has terminated, or the specified
>   waiting time elapses.

Below pseudocode example which shows how it works :

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("command");
        Process p = pb.start();
        p.waitFor(...);
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question, because the waitFor(long) method is even in the old method.

Comment: Also this only deals with time limit, how will processBuilder API set memory limit? There is no way to do that in java probably. ulimit, prlimit, cgroups, systemd are solutions suggested by others(which might work)